# pd.DatetimeIndex keep returning the wrong month

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetimeindex

I am reading data from a csv file, and I have a Date column formatted as **"dd/mm/yyyy"**.

I just want to extract the month from it.

The problem is that in some cases (based on my observation it is when dd > 12), it returns the month correctly. Otherwise, it returns the day instead.

I tried extracting the day assuming that maybe the built-in format is **"mm/dd/yyyy"**, but the same problem occurs. Only the year gets extracted correctly.

I have tried reformatting the date by replacing **"/"** with **"-"** but it did not solve the issue.

This is the code for extracting the month:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
```

Here is an example of the results I'm obtaining.

```
Date: 19-01-2012,
Month: 01

Date: 04-01-2012,
Month: 04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the `format="%d-%m-%Y`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date':["19-01-2012","04-01-2012"]})

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format="%d-%m-%Y").dt.month

print(df)
```

```
       date     month
0  19-01-2012      1
1  04-01-2012      1
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is recast the `df['Date']` column as a datetime.

You can specify that the days are first with the dayfirst parameter.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

When I use this with your example, and extract the months with:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).month
```

I see both months as 1 for January.